# JQuery Datatable reverts to default on get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

Hello I have a button when clicked on , removes a row from the datatable and then redraws itself. I've tried [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) but it reverts my datatable to default settings while removing the row:

```
var tbl;
$(document).ready(function() {
    tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "columns": [{
            "width": "50%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }],
        "responsive": true,
        "retrieve": true
    });
});

function delete()
   tbl.rows($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
}
```

I've tried this too and I get the same result:

```
function delete()
   $('#myTable').DataTable().rows($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
}
```

And also I tried including [reinitializing](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) the table but I get an error

```
function delete() {
    var tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "columns": [{
            "width": "50%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }],
        "responsive": true,
        "retrieve": true
    });

    tbl.rows($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You need indicate the `row` to delete, `this` in this case not reference to element.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code and I haven't seen the HTML... but anyways, here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/quhologaba/1/edit

code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "responsive": true,
        "retrieve": true
    });

  $('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', '.remove', function () {
    alert('clicked');
    console.log(tbl);
    tbl.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();
  } );

});
```